# Bootstrap navbar transparent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

For some reason I cannot get the navbar to change. I tried to make it transparent. I know bootstrap navbar is normally an image so I included `background-image: none`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#intro">Eric West</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't remove .navbar-inverse (or .navbar-default) unless you plan on adding some custom CSS to make up for it because these add properties to the nav, in particular to the `navbar-toggle` class.

Without one of those you'll remove alot of CSS from your nav and the `navbar-toggle` will not be visible on a device under 768px, it will be there and actionable but you won't be able to see it.

I would add a custom nav class and use that to override the property you need to change.

See example with that includes one with and one without the additional property.

```css
body,
html {
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#intro">Custom Navbar</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#projects">Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-2"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#intro">Navbar Only</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#projects">Projects</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a typo on your end, but you need to add a `.` to target the navbar class in css like so:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
```

As mentioned by @Benya16, the `navbar-inverse` class modifies the base attributes of the navbar, you can read about that in the docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-inverted). If you remove that bootstrap attribute it will be the bootstrap default.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstraps Navbar is defined by its CSS file. To change the color, simply do`.navbar-default:background-color: transparent !important` although !important is not best practise, you can always change the color in the Bootstrap.css file.

Bootstrap.css - line 4594 to find the .navbar-inverse background color.

do ctrl-f and type navbar-defualt to find that one too.