# Bootstrap Navbar has strange hairline border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i have tried everything to get rid of this bloody hairline, including the techniques from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044657/bootstrap-3-nav-bar-change-color-cause-showing-a-white-border-or-white-line) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595084/bootstrap-navbar-transparent) but no soap.  here's an image of what i am dealing with:

[image: white hairline border on navbar]

it crosses the entire header of the page and for the love of everything webby, i cannot locate where it is coming from!  just basic navbar with a transparent background.  i've plumbed the entire CSS listing in devtools and the closest thing i found was a `border-color` on `.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form`, which i tried changing to no effect.

any enlightenment is most welcome at this stage.  TIA!

WR!

Comment: Do you have the border-width set to 0px?

Comment: on which selector?  .navbar? yes.

Comment: posting your code or better yet a working codepen would be most helpful.

Comment: copy that.  i'll get on it later today.

Comment: okay.  here's the codepen.  have NO idea why the menu is now vertical, but that's not the point.  the hairline is there plain as day.  https://codepen.io/iansebryk/pen/RLBbQv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.navbar-default` has a box-shadow, which is what you can see:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
```

Override it in your own CSS to get rid of that line:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrBWaR).

Comment: that's the bunny right there... never though to check that!  thank you.  and apologies for taking so long to respond.  :P